# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2x-1}$ converge uniformly on $(-\infty, -a), a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm currently using Rudins book and this problem is not one of the listed exercises, but I want to try to understand it.

My work:
Define $S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2x-1}$. Then $\left\vert S_n-S_m\right\vert=\left\vert\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{k^2x-1}\right\vert=\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\left\vert\frac{1}{k^2x-1}\right\vert$. I want to find an upper bound for this difference but all I have is $|k^2x-1|=k^2x+(-1)|\leq |k^2x|+1$ which doesn't help.

Any tips?

Comment: You would have to find a lower bound for $\lvert k^2x-1\rvert$ to get an upper bound for the series.

Comment: Hi @vitamind, I agree. I considered using $|k^2x-k$, but that won't help me get rid of $x$. Since I'm trying to prove uniform convergence, I don't think I can fix x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in (-\infty,-a)$ with $a>0$, then $\frac{1}{n^{2}x-1}$ is always negative and:

$$|\frac{1}{n^{2}x-1}|= \frac{1}{n^{2}|x|+1}$$

So $S_{k} = -\sigma_{k}$ where $\sigma_{k} = \sum^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{2}|x|+1}$.

$$ \sigma_{k} = \sum^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{2}|x|+1} <  \sum^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{2}|x|} = \frac{1}{|x|}\sum^{k}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^{2}} $$

Assuming the solution of the Basel problem (you will have a small follow-up exercise to prove boundedness of the comparison series if you can't assume this), you know that {$\sigma_{k}$} is a monotone bounded sequence and thus converges, therefore {$S_{k}$} wth $S_{k} = -\sigma_{k}$ also converges, either by the same reasoning (monotone bounded sequence) or by nature of the relationship.

To finish the uniformity given convergence of {$\sigma_{k}$} to \sigma' consider that:

$$ \sigma' - \sigma_{k} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{1}{n^{2}|x|+1} <  \sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{1}{n^{2}|x|} = \frac{1}{|x|}\sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{1}{n^{2}} <  \frac{1}{a}\sum^{\infty}_{n=k+1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

Therefore given $\epsilon > 0$ There is a $M$ such that $|S_{j}-S'| < \epsilon$ for all $j>M$ for every $x\in (-\infty,-a)$.